# struts 2 + hibernate + spring + ehcache

Tags: hibernate, spring, assemblies, struts, ehcache

i have struts v2.3.3, hibernate v3.2.1, spring v3.0.5, and ehcache v2.4.2 (with ehcache spring annotations v 1.1.3). in one way or another, some of these projects depend on asm (directly or indirectly through another project). as far as i can tell, struts v2.3.3 needs asm v3.1. hibernates needs as v1.5.3. if i take out asm v3.1, struts dependency is broken, and if i take out asm 1.5.3, hibernate dependency is broken. if i leave both versions in, struts complain (NoSuchMethodError on org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(..)).

can someone please advise what to do?

i cannot use hibernate cache only because some of my data access objects (DAOs) do not access database; they access their data in other ways (i.e. from the web via web services).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply upgrade hibernate core to the latest version?
The [3.5.6 version](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.5.Final) doesn't depend on asm

Comment: i will try that, but i don't know if it will be "simply upgrade". who knows what other dependencies will break or be introduced (which is why i am in this situation in the first place).

Comment: you're using the latest version of every framework against a very old version of hibernate, so it is high likely that there are no solution to your original question